# Javascript full comparison function

Tags: javascript, performance, comparison

I am developing a complete library (in Javascript) containing main structures and algorithms.
I need to design a compare function in order to compare every kind of data.

I’ll use this function as:

a = some data (string, number, object, array, ...)

b = some data (string, number, object, array, ...)

b.compare(a) :

- 0 if a is equal to b
- 1 if  b i greater than
- -1 if b is less than a

I designed my version and I got inspired by _.eq of underscore.js framework.

What do you think about it? 
Is there any better way to implement it?

```
function compare (a, b, aStack, bStack) {

        // with this I can youse compare as b.compare(a)
        b = b || this.data;

        // Unwrap any wrapped objects.
        if (b instanceof ObjectNode) b = b.data;
        if (a instanceof ObjectNode) a = a.data;

        // Identical objects are equal. `0 === -0`, but they aren't identical.
        // See the [Harmony `egal` proposal](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:egal).
        if (a === b) {
            if(a !== 0) return 0;
            else if(1 / a === 1 / b) return 0;
            else return (1 / b > 1 / a)? 1 : -1;
        }
        // A strict comparison is necessary because `null == undefined`.
        if (a == null || b == null || a == undefined || b == undefined) {
            if(a === b) return 0;
            /* Now I am defining:
            (NaN > null)
            null > undefined
            null < everything else
            undefined < everything */
            if(a == undefined) return 1;
            if(b == undefined) return -1;
            if(a == null)   return 1;
        }

        // Compare `[[Class]]` names.
        var className = toString.call(a);
        if (className !== toString.call(b)) {

            // In this case I compare strings;
            if(className < toString.call(b)) 1;
            if(className > toString.call(b)) -1;

        }
        switch (className) {
                // Strings, numbers, regular expressions, dates, and booleans are compared by value.
            case '[object RegExp]':
                // RegExps are coerced to strings for comparison (Note: '' + /a/i === '/a/i')
            case '[object String]':
                // Primitives and their corresponding object wrappers are equivalent; thus, `"5"` is
                // equivalent to `new String("5")`.
                if('' + a === '' + b) return 0;
                if('' + a < '' + b) return 1;
                if('' + a > '' + b) return -1;

            case '[object Number]':
                // `NaN`s are equivalent, but non-reflexive.
                // Object(NaN) is equivalent to NaN
                // Nan is less than anyother but bigger than undefined and than null
                if (+a !== +a) return (+b !== +b)? 0 : 1;
                // An `egal` comparison is performed for other numeric values.
                if (+a === 0) return  (1 / +b === 1 / a)? 0 : ((1 / +b > 1 / a)? 1 : -1);
                return (+a === +b)? 0 : (+b > +a)? 1 : -1;
            case '[object Date]':
            case '[object Boolean]':
                // Coerce dates and booleans to numeric primitive values. Dates are compared by their
                // millisecond representations. Note that invalid dates with millisecond representations
                // of `NaN` are not equivalent.
                return (+a === +b) ? 0 : (+b > +a)? 1 : -1;
        }

        var areArrays = className === '[object Array]';
        if (!areArrays) {
            if (typeof a != 'object') return 1;
            if (typeof b != 'object') return -1;

            // Objects with different constructors are not equivalent, but `Object`s or `Array`s
            // from different frames are.
            var aCtor = a.constructor, bCtor = b.constructor;
            if (aCtor !== bCtor && !((typeof aCtor == 'function') && aCtor instanceof aCtor &&
                                     (typeof bCtor == 'function') && bCtor instanceof bCtor)
                && ('constructor' in a && 'constructor' in b)) {
                return b>a? 1 : -1;
            }
        }
        // Assume equality for cyclic structures. The algorithm for detecting cyclic
        // structures is adapted from ES 5.1 section 15.12.3, abstract operation `JO`.

        // Initializing stack of traversed objects.
        // It's done here since we only need them for objects and arrays comparison.
        aStack = aStack || [];
        bStack = bStack || [];
        var length = aStack.length;
        while (length--) {
            // Linear search. Performance is inversely proportional to the number of
            // unique nested structures.
            if (aStack[length] === a) return bStack[length] === b;
        }

        // Add the first object to the stack of traversed objects.
        aStack.push(a);
        bStack.push(b);

        // Recursively compare objects and arrays.
        if (areArrays) {
            // Compare array lengths to determine if a deep comparison is necessary.
            length = a.length;
            if (length !== b.length) return b.length>a.length? 1 : -1;
            // Deep compare the contents, ignoring non-numeric properties.
            var res;
            while (length--) {
                if ( (res = this.compare(a[length], b[length], aStack, bStack)) != 0) return res;
            }
        } else {
            // Deep compare objects.
            var keys = Object.keys(a), key;
            length = keys.length;
            // Ensure that both objects contain the same number of properties before comparing deep equality.
            if (Object.keys(b).length !== length) return (Object.keys(b).length > length)? 1 : -1;
            while (length--) {
                // Deep compare each member
                key = keys[length];
                if (!(hasOwnProperty.call(b, key) && (res = this.compare(a[key], b[key], aStack, bStack)) === 0)) return res;
            }
        }
        // Remove the first object from the stack of traversed objects.
        aStack.pop();
        bStack.pop();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This questions seems better suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You definitely should split this up per type.